# Get the last item in an array from Order Notes in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, php-7

I want to include the last Order Note in an email going out to customers. At the moment it outputs all the order notes, how can I edit this foreach to only show the  last/latest order note?

The installation uses PHP 7.2 but ideally I would like it to work across all versions, should I drop back to PHP 5.6 that I have used previously on my test site

```
<h2><?php _e( 'Order Notes', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

<?php
$args = array(
    'status' => 'approve',
    'post_id' => $order->id
);
$comments = get_comments($args);
foreach($comments as $comment) :
    echo $comment->comment_content . '<br />';
endforeach;
?>
```

So the desired outcome would show "Order status changed from on-hold to completed"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the foreach statement and use the `end()` function like this:

```
$lastcomment = end($comments);
echo $lastcomment->comment_content . '<br />';
```